# How to split a list with only one item which is a complex string?

Tags: python, regex

I was processing a xml document and the output is a list of legth 1, whose only node is of this form.

```
[['2007-12-18'],
 ['AAAA'],
 ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'],

 ['Objetos de Aprendizagem', u'Personaliza\\xe7\\xe3o',
   u'Perfil do Usu\\xe1rio', u'Padr\\xf5es de Metadados',
   u'Vers\\xf5es de Objetos de Aprendizagem',
   'Agrupamento de Objetos Similares'],

 ['2007-12-18'],

 [u'LOCPN: CADEIA DE PRODU\\xc7\\xc3O'],

 [u'Maria de F\\xe1tima', 'ZZZ', 'Albert Einstein',
   'James Clerk Maxwell', u'Jos\\xe9 da Silva',
   'DDD', 'R M. C. A'],

 ['Objetos de Aprendizagem', 'Modelo de Processo',
   'Redes de Petri Colorida', u'Especifica\\xe7\\xe3o formal'],

 ['2007-12-18'],

 [u'COMPUTA\\xc7\\xc3O M\\xd3VEL E UB\\xcdQUA  GRADUA\\xc7\\xc3O DE REFER\\xcaNCIA'],

 ['JB Cardoso', 'Franz Ferdinand', 'Nick Nolte',
   u'S\\xe9rgio Madruga', u'D\\xe9bora JKLJ'],

 [u'Computa\\xe7\\xe3o M\\xf3vel e Ub\\xedqua',
   u'Gradua\\xe7\\xe3o de Refer\\xeancia', u' Educa\\xe7\\xe3o Ub\\xedqua']
 ]
```

I need to split the string of the node[0], into sublists of this form:

```
[date, title, ['a','b','...'],[keyword1,keywork2,...,keywordN]].
```

I have been working on it, and tried different ways. Since the original list is of length 1, I can split it. I get "out of range" error. I have tried to split the string, but could find no way, if I use comma as separator, the new created list has length 35, since each word is counted as a list item. Each sublist represents a publication and I need to acces each  item in order to create a graph database. Does someone could help me? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try to use the formatting tools. Also if you tried something try to post your code so we may help you improve it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'original list' ???

Comment: For 'original list' I mean the submitted list composed by one long peculiar string. I made a mistake: the correct is "Since the original list is of lenght 1, I can't split it, but observe that, since the node[0] has the "big string". I was searching for a way to split this string and create sublists. The suggestion of [Simon](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1960027/simon) worked fine.

Comment: I didn't understand your question because you wrote that the list is of length 1 while it is of length 12, and you wrote you tried to split the string while there isn't only one string but several strings in the sublists, and the content of the general list isn't a string but 12 sublists. That's bad expression. - By the way, see my comment to Simon's answer

Comment: By the way again, see the function ``pprint`` in module ``pprint``, it is very good to print complex lists and other complex objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
>>> x = [
['2007-12-18'], ['AAAA'],
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'], 
['Objetos de Aprendizagem', u'Personaliza\\xe7\\xe3o', u'Perfil do Usu\\xe1rio',
u'Padr\\xf5es de Metadados', u'Vers\\xf5es de Objetos de Aprendizagem', 'Agrupamento de Objetos Similares'], 
['2007-12-18'],
[u'LOCPN: CADEIA DE PRODU\\xc7\\xc3O'],
[u'Maria de F\\xe1tima', 'ZZZ', 'Albert Einstein', 'James Clerk Maxwell',
u'Jos\\xe9 da Silva', 'DDD', 'R M. C. A'],
['Objetos de Aprendizagem', 'Modelo de Processo', 'Redes de Petri Colorida', 
u'Especifica\\xe7\\xe3o formal'], 
['2007-12-18'], 
[u'COMPUTA\\xc7\\xc3O M\\xd3VEL E UB\\xcdQUA  GRADUA\\xc7\\xc3O DE REFER\\xcaNCIA'],
['JB Cardoso', 'Franz Ferdinand', 'Nick Nolte', u'S\\xe9rgio Madruga', u'D\\xe9bora    JKLJ'],
[u'Computa\\xe7\\xe3o M\\xf3vel e Ub\\xedqua', u'Gradua\\xe7\\xe3o de Refer\\xeancia', u' Educa\\xe7\\xe3o Ub\\xedqua']
]
```

... the following list comprehension will split the list into sublists containing the date, title and the two following lists:

```
>>> [x[j:j+4] for j in range(0,len(x),4)]
```

(edited to simplify the original version of this comprehension by using the increment in the `range()`, as suggested by @eyquem)

... giving:

```
[
[['2007-12-18'], ['AAAA'], ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'], 
['Objetos de Aprendizagem', 'Personaliza\\xe7\\xe3o', 'Perfil do Usu\\xe1rio',
'Padr\\xf5es de Metadados', 'Vers\\xf5es de Objetos de Aprendizagem', 
'Agrupamento de Objetos Similares']], 
[['2007-12-18'], ['LOCPN: CADEIA DE PRODU\\xc7\\xc3O'], ['Maria de F\\xe1tima', 
'ZZZ','Albert Einstein', 'James Clerk Maxwell', 'Jos\\xe9 da Silva', 'DDD', 
'R M. C. A'],
['Objetos de Aprendizagem', 'Modelo de Processo', 'Redes de Petri Colorida',
'Especifica\\xe7\\xe3o formal']], 
[['2007-12-18'], ['COMPUTA\\xc7\\xc3O M\\xd3VEL E UB\\xcdQUA  GRADUA\\xc7\\xc3O DE REFER\\xcaNCIA'], 
['JB Cardoso', 'Franz Ferdinand', 'Nick Nolte', 'S\\xe9rgio Madruga', 
'D\\xe9bora JKLJ'],
['Computa\\xe7\\xe3o M\\xf3vel e Ub\\xedqua', 
'Gradua\\xe7\\xe3o de Refer\\xeancia', ' Educa\\xe7\\xe3o Ub\\xedqua']]
]
```

That makes it easy to parse the list content.

Comment: You divide by 4 in ``len(x)//4`` and after that you multiply by 4 in ``4*i``. Just do ``[x[j:j+4] for j in xrange(0,len(x),4)]``